# Delete entity with inheritance does not work with spring data

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm trying to delete an entity "study" that extends "entry". The inheritance strategy is `InheritanceType.JOINED`.
There is a study table and an entry table (with common fields).

Two repositories are defined:

```
EntryRepository extends CrudRepository<Entry, String>
StudyRepository extends CrudRepository<Study, String>
```

These two repositories extends the spring data `org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository`.

The problem is: the delete method for these two repository is not working. No error, no effect. For other entities (without inheritance), it works well.

Here is my test code:

```
 System.out.println("entity exist?: " + entryRepository.existsById(entry.getId()));
 System.out.println("before delete parent: " + entryRepository.count());
 entryRepository.delete(entry);
 System.out.println("after delete parent: " + entryRepository.count());

 System.out.println("entity exist?: " + studyRepository.existsById(entry.getId()));
 System.out.println("before delete child1: " + studyRepository.count());
 studyRepository.delete((Study)entry);
 System.out.println("after delete child1: " + studyRepository.count());
```

The log results:

```
Hibernate: select count(*) as col_0_0_ from entry entry0_ where entry0_."ID"=?
entity exist?: true
Hibernate: select count(*) as col_0_0_ from entry entry0_
before delete parent: 6
Hibernate: select count(*) as col_0_0_ from entry entry0_
after delete parent: 6

Hibernate: select count(*) as col_0_0_ from study study0_ inner join entry study0_1_ on study0_."ID"=study0_1_."ID" where study0_."ID"=?
entity exist?: true
Hibernate: select count(*) as col_0_0_ from study study0_ inner join entry study0_1_ on study0_."ID"=study0_1_."ID"
before delete child1: 3
Hibernate: select count(*) as col_0_0_ from study study0_ inner join entry study0_1_ on study0_."ID"=study0_1_."ID"
after delete child1: 3
```

So...no delete in log, no error,... :-/
Any idea on how to get that working or how to get the origin of this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Check if all the values(other than ID field also) set in the java object match with the data in the Database table

Comment: Do you execute **all** code in the same transaction? Also, what database?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Are you trying to delete two separate objects or the same object twice? You haven't declared your `@Inheritence` annotation correctly or you wouldn't be seeing `inner join` in the sql instead of the expected `where study0_.dtype='Study'`

Comment: @aka-one: yes same transaction (h2 database (disk)).

Comment: @K.Nicholas I'm just trying to delete the entity. I don't want to delete it twice, I'm just showing that with the parent or the child repository, it doesn't work. Of course in my code, I should only delete it once.

Comment: Can you show the entire test class?